# How to draw a picture like this in LaTeX?

Tags: graph, tree, latex

I want to draw two graphs like the picture below? How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [how to draw a graph in latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985507/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-latex)

Comment: There’s a specialized [Stack Exchange site for TeX users](http://tex.stackexchange.com), your question might fit better there. (And may get moved automatically after a while.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/), it exports a manual script like

```
digraph vis{
rankdir=LR;
"P"->"Q";
"P"->"R";
"Q"->"S";
"S"->"T";
}
```

as a *.eps file (and many other types), JUST LIKE THE ONE YOU POSTED HERE, which you can reference in your {figure} block in your tex