# Draw graphs (graph theory) with LaTex

Tags: latex

I am currently writing an article about graph theory in LaTex and I am curious how to create graphs like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkD5s.png (example by my tutor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a graph in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985507/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-latex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ is a nice LaTeX package to handle drawing graphs. Here are some examples: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/

I recreated your graph in particular using TikZ. Here is the result.
[image: Graph producible by TikZ]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzset{enclosed/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.15cm, fill=black}}

      \node[enclosed, label={left, yshift=.2cm: E}] (E) at (0.75,3.25) {};
      \node[enclosed, label={above, xshift=.2cm: H}] (H) at (3,4) {};
      \node[enclosed, label={right, yshift=0cm: B}] (B) at (4.5,2) {};
      \node[enclosed, label={below, xshift=.2cm: M}] (M) at (3,0) {};
      \node[enclosed, label={left, yshift=-.2cm: L}] (L) at (0.75,0.75) {};

      \draw (E) -- (H) node[midway, sloped, above] (edge1) { $\infty$};
      \draw (H) -- (B) node[midway, right] (edge2) {288};
      \draw (B) -- (M) node[midway, right] (edge3) {585};
      \draw (L) -- (M) node[midway, below] (edge4) {$\infty$};
      \draw (E) -- (L) node[midway, left] (edge5) {640};
      \draw (E) -- (B) node[midway, above] (edge6) {$\infty$};
      \draw (E) -- (M) node[midway, left] (edge7) {$\infty$};
      \draw (L) -- (H) node[midway, left] (edge8) {$\infty$};
      \draw (L) -- (B) node[midway, below] (edge9) {$\infty$};
      \draw (H) -- (M) node[midway, right] (edge10) {775};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer! However please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, better use `\tikzset`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized! Just updated the answer to use tikzset instead :)